# Issues with using Jump Host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sftp, scp

How do I transfer a file from my local machine to a remote host to which I need to get through a jump host? These are the steps I follow to connect to the remote host

```
1. ssh myname@jump-host
2. enter password
3. sudo su - another-random-name
4. ssh name@remote-host
```

Now I want to transfer a file from my local machine to the remote-host. How would I achieve this? I have already tried `scp -oProxyCommand` but I don't quite know where I should include step 3 as part of this command?

Comment: You can use SSH [port forwarding](http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html)

Comment: In step 3 you are switching to user that can connect to remote-host without password using certificate. This would pose main hurdle for port forwarding. When you will try to do it as @Yedidia described, then you will need to get SSH private key for another-random-name to your local computer. And I am not sure if you are allowed to do that (I don't mean technically).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Use port forwarding to get third host ssh port on your localhost, in this way:

```
ssh -L 2222:remote-host:22 myname@jump-host
```

then (on another tab/shell on first host):

```
scp -P 2222 file myname@localhost:
```

will copy directly to remote host.

Answer (score 0):

On the jump host under another-random-name run

```
ssh -L 2222:remote-host:22 myname@jump-host
```

then on your local computer you can run

```
scp -P 2222 file name@jump-host:
```

SCP will try to connect to `jump-host`, while in fact this connection will be forwarded to jump-host. And will use `name` as it is connecting to remote-host.
You are probably still facing problem with certificate for another-random-user. You can either create certificate on your machine for your-local-user and put public key on remote-host in user allowed keys.

Comment: Hi Markek, this creates link/folder in my local directory name@jump-host. doesn't put anything in the jump-host?

Comment: No this will not store any data on jump-host. The first command opens TCP port 2222 on jump-host and forwards all communication to port 22 on remote-host without storing it locally.