# MySQL connection in GUI via two ssh connections on Mint

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh, linux-mint, dbeaver

Apologies if this is in some way a duplicate - I couldn't find anything that covered this (at least in a way that I could understand made it similar).

Here's a basic diagram of my connections:

Laptop => SSH server 1 => SSH server 2 => MySQL (MariaDB)

I can use terminal to jump across to server 2 as per the usual methods:

```
ssh -t user@server1 ssh -p99 user@server2
```

Then, in the terminal, I can `mysql -uroot -p` as normal.

*(connections amended to remove details, of course)*

I have attempted a few different things to try and get a direct connection in DBeaver, but I can't seem to make it work with that extra ssh connection (in*ssh*eption - it's new to me).  I've found, and have been playing with, Gnome Connection Manager to try and make this happen - I'm used to Win tools like Penguinet, which isn't available on Linux, but it does look to be capable.

I'm probably just out of my depth, but I am thinking that this should be simple - but I just can't get the hang of how to get this going.

I'm expecting that at some point I'll be able to connect to `127.0.0.1:1234` in DBeaver (SQL GUI), but I'm just struggling to make that happen.

Does anyone have a moment to advise the best method to daisy-chain the connections together?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44756915/8113019) It has answer to your question. Just use ssh port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

Use port forwarding with SSH to bring remote port to your local machine.

```
ssh -L 1234:server1:1234 -t user@server1 ssh -L 1234:server2:1234 -p99  user@server2
```

Now you can connect to `localhost:1234` and your connection will be forwarded to server2:1234. Just make sure that port 1234 on server1 and localhost are not in use.